# Restrict scope of HTML autocompletion

Tags: html, forms, autocomplete

I have a web application with frontend on / and backend on /backend, both have different login-sets.

Currently, the autocompletion fills the frontend user/pass also in backend, and vice versa - any way to prevent this, but still allow user/pass autocompletion?

Thanks!

Comment: This has been asked before

Comment: Did not appear in the searchbox while creating, unfortunately I don't know the exact technical term for what I need. Can you please point me to the previous question?

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood your question, have you tried giving the inputs different id's and names?

Answer (score 0):

```
<form autocomplete ="off">
```

or use

```
<input type="text" autocomplete ="off">
```

Comment: This disables autocomplete which sucks for user experience!

Answer (score 0):

You could simply clean the value of the form using Javascript after the load of the page is completed.

Comment: Also not; anything that prevents autocomplete is not an option, it forces people to use a "use-everywhere" password so they're able to remember them... (My scope is low-tech users)